# ¿Cómo remplazar la doble barra inversa a una sola barra inversa?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Holi quiero hacer que esta cadena pase de esto:

```
'hola\\n\n'
```

a esto:

```
'hola\n'
```

ya intenté con el replace pero me arroja este resultado:(

```
'hola\\n'
```

he aquí el codigo jjjj

```
'hola\\n\n'.rstrip("\n").replace("\\\\","\\")
#primero elimina el salto de linea| luego remplaza el \\ por un \
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para aquellos que estén interesados en "des-escapar" las cadenas sin perder los caracteres especiales como letras con tilde y ñ, hice una expresión regular para detectar todas las secuencias de escape escapadas mencionadas en [la documentacion](https://docs.python.org/es/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).

Esta expresión regular se puede usar para reemplazar los caracteres escapados por sus versiones sin escapar. Uso el mismo método que la propuesta final de [otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/527025/158880).

Otras guias usadas:

- De aquí vienen casi todos los ejemplos usados: https://linuxconfig.org/list-of-python-escape-sequence-characters-with-examples

---

###### Código

```
import re

# Creo la tupla de secuencias de escape
scape_secuence_detecter = (re.escape("\\"),
                           re.escape(r"'"),
                           re.escape(r'"'),
                           re.escape(r"a"),
                           re.escape(r"b"),
                           re.escape(r"f"),
                           re.escape(r"n"),
                           re.escape(r"r"),
                           re.escape(r"t"),
                           re.escape(r"v"),
                           r"[0-7]{1,3}", # basado en https://stackoverflow.com/a/34750174/12913664 y la documentación
                           r"x[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}", # basado en https://stackoverflow.com/a/5317339/12913664 y la documentacion
                           r"N\{[^\}]+\}",
                           r"u[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}",
                           r"U[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}")

# creo la expresión regular dinamicamente. En este caso le indico que debe empezar con \
# y continuar con el primer item de la tupla, si no el segundo, si no el tercero, etc.
scape_secuence_detecter = re.compile(r"\\({regexs})".format(regexs="|".join(f"({regex})" for regex in scape_secuence_detecter)))

def unescape_string(string):
    # esta parte 'f"\{m[1]}".encode().decode("unicode_escape")' sirve para tomar lo que viene después de las \ escapadas
    # ponerle una barra sin escapar y convertir esa cadena en una secuencia de escape.
    return scape_secuence_detecter.sub(lambda m:f"\{m[1]}".encode().decode("unicode_escape"), string)

to_test = (r"\\",
           r"\'",
           r"\"",
           r"\a",
           r"ab\bc",
           r"hello\fworld",
           r"hello\nworld",
           r"\N{DAGGER}",
           r"123456\rXX_XX",
           r"\t* hello",
           r"\u041b",
           r"\U000001a9",
           r"\043",
           r"\x23",
           r"\x23\\na")

print("Regex:", scape_secuence_detecter.pattern)
print()

for string in to_test:
    with_codecs = string.encode().decode("unicode_escape")

    print("Antes:", string)

    string = unescape_string(string)

    print("Despues:", string)
    print("Usando Encoding+decoding:", with_codecs)
    print("-"*10)
```

###### Produce

```
Regex: \\((\\)|(')|(")|(a)|(b)|(f)|(n)|(r)|(t)|(v)|([0-7]{1,3})|(x[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})|(N\{[^\}]+\})|(u[0-9A-Fa-f]{4})|(U[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}))

Antes: \\
Despues: \
Usando Encoding+decoding: \
----------
Antes: \'
Despues: '
Usando Encoding+decoding: '
----------
Antes: \"
Despues: "
Usando Encoding+decoding: "
----------
Antes: \a
Despues: 
Usando Encoding+decoding: 
----------
Antes: ab\bc
Despues: abc
Usando Encoding+decoding: abc
----------
Antes: hello\fworld
Despues: helloworld
Usando Encoding+decoding: helloworld
----------
Antes: hello\nworld
Despues: hello
world
Usando Encoding+decoding: hello
world
----------
Antes: \N{DAGGER}
Despues: †
Usando Encoding+decoding: †
----------
Antes: 123456\rXX_XX
Despues: 123456
XX_XX
Usando Encoding+decoding: 123456
XX_XX
----------
Antes: \t* hello
Despues:    * hello
Usando Encoding+decoding:   * hello
----------
Antes: \u041b
Despues: Л
Usando Encoding+decoding: Л
----------
Antes: \U000001a9
Despues: Ʃ
Usando Encoding+decoding: Ʃ
----------
Antes: \043
Despues: #
Usando Encoding+decoding: #
----------
Antes: \x23
Despues: #
Usando Encoding+decoding: #
----------
Antes: \x23\\na
Despues: #\na
Usando Encoding+decoding: #\na
----------
```

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

El string `'hola\\n\n'` en realidad no tiene una doble barra invertida, en realidad es una barra invertida pero con secuencia de escape

Si hacemos print al `string` obtenemos lo siguiente (Nota que hay una nueva línea al final y que `\n` es parte del texto visible):

```
hola\n
```

Si quisieras tratar el string como texto crudo puedes utilizar el prefijo `r` y al hacer `print()` vas a ver todos los caracteres tal cual aparecen en el `string`

```
print(r'hola\\n\n')
```

Devuelve

```
hola\\n\n
```

Por lo que, si quieres únicamente quitar el `\n` del final y en el texto ver `hola\n` entonces sólo necesitas el `rstrip()`, pero ten en cuenta que `\\n` en realidad es `\n` pero con la secuencia de escape de la barra invertida

Si lo que deseas es que `\n` actúe como salto de línea y no que se muestre como texto, entonces puedes utilizar `encode()` y `decode()`

```
s = 'hola\\n\n'.rstrip("\n")
print(s.encode().decode('unicode_escape'))
```

Esto devuelve el texto crudo `'hola\n'` y si haces `print` devolvería

```
hola
```

Comment: gracias por el comentario pero ¿Qué pasa si al final tenemos a "\\t\n" o al principio o tal vez en el medio? ese proceso podría quedar inutilizable, como dice en el titulo necesito que esas dos barras invertidas sean solo una barra invertida para así poder manipular las strings como si fuesen un texto crudo lol

Comment: Ah ok, ya entiendo, una pregunta, el string viene de algún otro lado o tu lo escribes?

Comment: viene de un tk.text

Comment: Buen día, edité la respuesta y agregué la explicación de lo que sucede, de esta forma podrías seguir utilizando cualquier caracter especial como `\n` o `\t` que venga en el texto

Comment: buen día, ya ha funcionado correctamente gracias <3

Comment: Tu respuesta con encode y decode no decodifica como se esperaría palabras con tildes y ñ. Por ejemplo niñéz se decodifica como niÃ±Ã©z

Comment: Así es, pero eso no era parte de la pregunta. De igual forma es bueno que el op lo sepa

Answer (score 0):

Si es posible que tenga varios `\n` puedes intentar con regex.

```py
import re

regex = r"(\\+n)+"

test_str = "hola\\n\n"

subst = "\n"

result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

print(result)
```

Donde el patrón `(\\+n)+` significa: `\\+` que es posible encontrar varias barras inclinadas consecutivamente, seguido de una `n`, y que lo anterior puede encontrarse también repetido `+`.

Comment: y en caso de que me tope con algún escape character que no sea necesariamente \\n?

Comment: @Elih ¿Podrías especificar el ejemplo en la pregunta? y ¿Cómo esperas la salida del ejemplo?

Comment: si en caso tenemos un 'hola\\tpedro\\n\n' espero de salida algo como 'hola\tpedro\n'